# Discontinuity in cdf function ($2$-dimension) is this uncountable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity

I'm studying probability theory, and I got one question in my mind.

It is clear that one dimension CDF has only countable discontinuities. Then when is two dimension, i.e.
$$F(x,y) = P(X \leq x , Y \leq y)$$
Is this function has uncountable discontinuity? I think so by gut feeling(think about only one singleton probability, i.e. $\delta_{(x,y)}$. But I want to prove it rigorously. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hints for a rigorous example:

- What is the CDF when for example there is a singleton probability $\mathbb P(X=x_0,Y=y_0)=1$ for given $x_0,y_0$? Clearly $F(x,y)=0$ or $1$ everywhere but which where?
- Where are the discontinuities in this CDF?
- What is the cardinality of the set of  locations of discontinuity?

Comment: I'm thinking same thing, but is it enough to prove that? for example, $P(X=x_0, Y = y_0) =0.5, P(X=x_0, Y = -y_0) =0.5$, then discontinuity might be change.

Comment: @probafds123 - having two points of positive probability just makes it more complicated but does not change the cardinality.